# Something I can use with React Native for web

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

I like React Native's some features like Flatlist, Modal, Animation. I wanted to develop for web with React Native or Expo. I use react navigation but have 404 errors in refresh pages. I also want When user put `www.mywebsite.com/post/postid`, it will go directly into postid's page. I tried react-router-dom with HashBrowser. Not great! I kind of want something better than hash browser. What can I use? Any advice please.

Comment: All the feeatures are available for reactJS too. Not your best choice to use react native or web. even if it is technically possible. you get lost in mistakes and challenges that you wouldn't otherwise have. I take it from your question that you're pretty new too. so better start with the basics.

Comment: Can you give me a little more specific direction? What did I need to make dynamic websites? As much as I searched, I found Next.js, Express.js to use with React.js. But I use firebase as backend. Next.js looks good I think. But as I mentioned, I really like to use React Native's certain components, APIs. So, is Next.js good? or is there anything you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

I use also react-native-web and react-navigation. If you want the react-navigation to work with the links correct, you must set up the config object like the [documentantion](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)

If you don't set up correctly the config object, react-navigation doesn't throw errors in your console, but it doesn't work right!

The question was before 3 months, but I hope this answer helps someone, with the same problem!

Comment: hello, @loannis Apostolou, thanks you for your advice. It's my bad that I did not describe I have tried that config at the time when I posted the problem. And I tried netlify, github, firebase as hosting. It gives no error in firebase hosting. E.g. if I type `www.mywebsite.com/post/id`, firebase hosting shows the respective post, but not the others. But I kind of want the same thing with github because github is free and firebase is not.